# Where should I place "last night" for this to be natural?

Tags: idiomatic-language

Mom: How's it going with Dad and his new girlfriend? (she's asking because her son has told her earlier that they argue a lot.)

Son: Last night I heard them yell./I heard them yell last night./Last night I heard them yelling./I heard them yelling last night.

Where should I place "last night" for it to sound natural?

Also, would using the present continuous tense be better here? (yell/yelling)

Comment: Either way sounds natural. It depends whether it's the nature of the incident or its timing that comes to mind first.

Comment: As Kate Bunting says. AND . . . *I heard them yell* means they yelled once, in unison (at the same time as each other). *I heard them yelling* suggests they yelled for a while, as people might when having an argument.

Comment: "I heard them yelling last night." Is what I would choose